# Drawing an NSString with background color to fill rect

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-text

I have this code:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
style.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[ticketName.uppercaseString drawInRect:CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, badgeSize.width - UIBarcode.size.width, 44) withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: FONT_NORMALX(40), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor], NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style}];
```

That produces something like this:

[image]

What I want is for the background color (black) of "GA" to fill the given rect, such that its a big black bar with the text centered inside. Is this possible?

Comment: Try to add whitespaces and draw with them.

Comment: Use a `UIBezierCurve` to draw the rect, fill that, then draw the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @beyowulf suggested. USe UIBezierPath to daw the rect and then fill it with the string.

```
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Text Drawing
    CGRect textRect = //bezier Rect
    UIBezierPath* textPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: textRect];
    [UIColor.blackColor setFill];
    [textPath fill];

        NSString* textContent = @"GA";
        NSMutableParagraphStyle* textStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
        textStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        NSDictionary* textFontAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize: UIFont.smallSystemFontSize], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textStyle};

        CGFloat textTextHeight = [textContent boundingRectWithSize: CGSizeMake(textRect.size.width, INFINITY)  options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes: textFontAttributes context: nil].size.height;
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextClipToRect(context, textRect);
        [textContent drawInRect: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(textRect), CGRectGetMinY(textRect) + (CGRectGetHeight(textRect) - textTextHeight) / 2, CGRectGetWidth(textRect), textTextHeight) withAttributes: textFontAttributes];
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

This gives the result:

[image]

Comment: Well, that is easy if you know the place, where the string should be drawn. (And in this case you could simply use two views.) Usually you do not know that.